# Find Percentile of values partitioned by KEY in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to find the percentile of the value column grouped by the KEY.
For example, A1 Key values- should be grouped by and values corresponding to A1: 12
4
3
1
3
5

should be used for calculating percentile.
Similarly it should go on for all the keys present.
How can I achieve it in MS Excel.
Currently I am doing it manually for every single key, but how can i do it for n number of keys.
I have attached the screenshot as:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution but this array formula may work:

```
=IF(A2=A1;"";PERCENTILE(IF($A$2:$A$14=A2;$B$2:$B$14);0,9))
```

Becaue it's an array formula, it must be entered pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Just drag it down trough whole column of data:

[image]